# Please add "total votes on questions" and "total votes on answers" into /user/{id} API

Tags: feature-request, api, voting

Is there any chance that the following methods:

- Total votes on questions (N.B. NOT total score but total *number* of votes)
- Total votes on answers

Could be added to the API?

There are no threats to confidentiality of voting trends with these methods and no bad could come from their introduction.

Comment: Other than adding this so you can track badge progress, what benefit does it have?

Comment: Other than tracking badge progress what benefit do: `creation_date`, `last_access_date`, `up_vote_count`, `down_vote_count` have?
I like statistics and this is just another one that is nice to have, are there and *real* adverse reasons not to include the above methods in the API?